# Instagram app occasionally sets Origin header to "null" when browsing to another site via link in profile

Tags: cors, instagram

People sometimes link to our website in their instagram profile. If a user is using the instagram app and browses to our site via that link, and later POSTs a form on our site, very occasionally (maybe 1 in 10,000 users) the Origin Header is set to the string "null" in the POST request.

We have not been able to repro.

(Note: We separately integrate with instagram to provide a "book now" button and also see this behavior occasionally (also not reproducible) in the OAUTH flow.)

Here is a sample agent string:
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 262.0.0.15.327 (iPhone14,5; iOS 16_1_2; en_IQ; ar-IQ; scale=3.00; 1170x2532; 425379641)`

So far, we've only seen this happen on iOS/instagram browser.

Note: I'm wondering if perhaps instagram occasionally inserts an HTTP redirect (hidden from us) which triggers this?

Comment: FYI, browsers use the `null` origin in case of a cross-origin redirect occurring during a CORS request and also for requests issued from a sandboxed document (e.g. an iframe with a `sandbox` attribute).

Comment: Whatever you do, never allow the `null` origin in your CORS config, as anybody (including attackers) can get a hold of it, and it's not subject to the so-called "wildcard exception".

Comment: @jub0bs thanks for your comments. I believe I know where the links are coming from (within instagram app, linked from profile), so not in iFrame (I don't think) and no redirects (I don't think). And the origin is set under these conditions 99% of the time. So I'm wondering if perhaps *sometimes* there is a redirect or an iFrame. This might just be a question regarding what instagram does. Or it might be a question regarding CORS (my understanding of CORS is weak; but I have tried to think through all the cases where ORIGIN can be set to null; you mention two of them).

Comment: In addition, a request issued from a `data:` or `file:` URL will have origin `null`.